# clearInterval on hover AND if the element has a particular background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6sTMD/1/) that shows what I have so far. I would like it so that when the user hover overs the div with the background color red, the setInterval should stop so that div with the mouse over it should stay red and all the rest of divs remain the default color (white).

and when the mouse moves off the div the set interval continues.

```
            function bgChange(){
            for(var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++){
                if(i == count) arr[count].css('background-color', "red");
                else arr[count].css("background-color", "skyblue");
            }
            i++;
            if( i === arr.length){i =0;} 
                var color = $(".boxes").each(function(){//part of the code i 
                                                // tried adding but doesnt't work
                    $(this).css("background-color")
                })
                console.log(color)
//check the background color to see if its red. Also if the mouse is over the 
//particular div it should clear the interval and when the mouse moves out of the
// the div it should start rotating colors down the row
            }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6sTMD/1/) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the interval ID returned by the `setInterval()` method and use it clear the interval whenever required. Note that there is no way to restart an interval once cleared, but since you are using global variable, you can just start a new interval and it will continue where it had left off.

Since you are not using a class to add red background, you need to check the color itself and the red color is returned as `rgb(255, 0, 0)` which is what you should be comparing for the color. If you end up adding a class for backgound color red, you can compare using `$(this).hasClass('className')`.

Lastly, you need to add mouse hover methods to the `.boxes` so that when the mouse hovers in, you can check for the color and stop interval and also to start a new interval when the mouse hovers out.

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6sTMD/8/)

```
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
var intervalID = -1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxes").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this));
    });

    $(".boxes").hover(function () {
        if ($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            intervalID = -1;
        }
    },

    function () {
        if (intervalID == -1) {
            intervalID = setInterval(bgChange, 2000);
        }
    });

    function bgChange() {
        for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
            if (i == count) {
                arr[count].css('background-color', 'red');
            } else {
                arr[count].css('background-color', 'white');
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == arr.length) i = 0;
    }
    intervalID = setInterval(bgChange, 2000);
});
```

[*edit* -  apologies, I missed seeing you already have a red class - [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sTMD/9/) for red class]

Comment: does inervalId variable have to equal to a number "-1" can you set to anything. is it used for calculations

Comment: No, it is not used for anything else. I just used it as a flag. If you want you can just use `if ($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")` instead of `if (intervalID == -1) ` and don't even bother setting it as -1.

Comment: does the anonymous function make the $(this) applicable to the particular box

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I'm adding/removing a css class rather than setting the background color directly. Then on mousover, if the red class is set, stop the interval, and on mouseout, start the interval up again. The setInterval call must be saved as a variable in order to clear it later.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = [];
    var i = 0;
    $(".boxes").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this));
    });

    function bgChange() {
        for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
            if (i == count) arr[count].addClass('red');
            else arr[count].removeClass('red');
        }
        i++;
        if (i == arr.length) i = 0;
    }
    var interval = setInterval(bgChange, 2000);

    $(".boxes").mouseover(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('red')){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });

    $(".boxes").mouseout(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('red')){
            interval = setInterval(bgChange, 2000);
        }
    });

});
```